# Await async javascript in Angularjs run block

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, promise

I'm running some initialization code to populate my initial application state in the run() block. The initial app state requires an HTTP call to fetch some data to populate the state, however, the run block executes and bootstraps the application before the HTTP promise has resolved so my initial page state is not actually populated at the time the page shows.

How do I 'await' the initialization of the state before I bootstrap the application?

```js
const Run = (StoreService, ContentService) => {
  'ngInject';

  let appState = StoreService.getState();
  // Initialise Application State
  if (!appState) {

    const initialState = {
      $valid: {},
      labels: []
    };    
    
    // THIS METHOD NEEDS TO RESOLVE BEFORE THE APPLICATION IS BOOTSTRAPPED
    ContentService.getAllContent()
      .then(data => {
        StoreService.setState({
          ...initialState,
          labels: data
        });
        console.log('Content Saved');
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });    
  }
  
angular.module('app').run(Run);

angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('app'), ['app'], {
  strictDi: true
});
```

Comment: Please, explain exactly wht you want. If run http before any angular (https://medium.com/@thatisuday/manual-bootstrapping-angular-application-resolve-dependencies-before-angular-run-block-f572310bcb65), or you are happy to have services initialize before your call, but you want http call before controllers initialize?

Comment: The latter. I need the state to be initialised before the main controller runs so that the complete state will be available in the controller.

Comment: I personally prefer creating route state, that any other state extend and put calls their -- this way I have full control i.e. can show some beautiful loading while request is in progress.

Comment: Do you have an example of how you do this?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put `await` in front of the promise (or statement that returns a promise) that you want to await. Keep in mind that your program may go do other things when you do this. Also you would have to await everything that needs to be awaited, including the http call. More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

In your case you may need to handle

```
ContentService.getAllContent()
      .then(data => {
        StoreService.setState({
          ...initialState,
          labels: data
        });
        console.log('Content Saved');
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
```

`

differently. Instead of `.then()` you could await it, and since it returns a value when it resolves, you could put the `data` variable assignment in front. Then just write the logic after it.

```
try {
    const data = await ContentService.getAllContent();
    StoreService.setState({
        ...initialState,
        labels: data
    });
    console.log('Content Saved');
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
}
```

It is possible that you will also have to make `Run` async, so you'll also need to await that.

`const Run = async (StoreService, ContentService) => ...`

`angular.module('app').run(await Run);`

More info on await [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)